# subtotal wih conditonally group using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to group column name :`Check,Code No1,Code 2,Status and total result` in Number column according to group using `VBA`

**Data**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

**This is my code:**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim LastRowWs As Long, LastRowWs1 As Long, i As Long
    Dim Delrange As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    On Error GoTo Whoa

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1"): Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    ws1.Cells.Delete

    LastRowWs = ws.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowWs1 = LastRowWs

    ws.Range("A1:F" & LastRowWs).Copy ws1.Range("A1")

    With ws1

        .Columns("A:F").Sort Key1:=.Range("A:F"), Order1:=xlAscending, Key2:=.Range("B2") _
        , Order2:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, OrderCustom:=4, MatchCase:= _
        True, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, DataOption2 _
        :=xlSortNormal

        With .Range("A1:F" & LastRowWs1)
            .Subtotal GroupBy:=2, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(5), Replace:=False, _
            PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
            .Subtotal GroupBy:=3, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(5), Replace:=False, _
            PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
            .Subtotal GroupBy:=4, Function:=xlSum, TotalList:=Array(5), Replace:=False, _
            PageBreaks:=False, SummaryBelowData:=True
        End With

        LastRowWs1 = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        '.Rows(LastRowWs1 + 1 & ":" & Rows.Count).ClearContents

        .Range("A1:F" & LastRowWs1).Copy
        .Range("A1:F" & LastRowWs1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        i = LastRowWs1
        Do While i > 1
        'If InStr(1, .Range("A" & i).Value, "", vbTextCompare) Then

            If InStr(1, .Range("D" & i).Value, "Total", vbTextCompare) Then
                i = i - 1
            Else
                If Delrange Is Nothing Then
                    Set Delrange = .Rows(i - 1)
                Else
                    Set Delrange = Union(Delrange, .Rows(i))
                     'i = i - 1
                End If
            End If
            i = i - 1
         ' End If
        Loop

        If Not Delrange Is Nothing Then Delrange.Delete: Set Delrange = Nothing

        LastRowWs1 = .Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlDown).Row

        'For i = LastRowWs1 To 2 Step -1
        For i = 1 To LastRowWs1
            If (InStr(1, .Range("D" & i).Value, "Total", vbTextCompare)) Then

                .Range("F" & i - 1).Value = .Range("F" & i).Value

                If Delrange Is Nothing Then
                    Set Delrange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                   Set Delrange = Union(Delrange, .Rows(i))
               End If
            End If

        Next i

        If Not Delrange Is Nothing Then Delrange.Delete

        .Cells.RemoveSubtotal
    End With

    MsgBox "Vandana, Please check Sheet 'Output' :-)"

LetsContinue:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    On Error Resume Next
    Set ws = Nothing: Set ws1 = Nothing
    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Sub
Whoa:
    MsgBox Err.Description
    Resume LetsContinue

End Sub
```

But result is like this

[image]

●★ 100 101 PG is same column group but sum result is separately

Comment: You can apply Pivot table for this. No need for VBA

Answer (score 1):

**See like this:**

[image]

Somethings you will need to change in Pivot Visualization:

- Tabular Form Data
- SubTotals Off
- Totals Off
- Item repeat for each column

[Link to File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JrsT33qF8Qv6nK1zhfdPTl7n36_NiCMX)